# what are the differences between いつも、度でも、何でも

Tags: words

I googled them, they share the very similar meaning and it confused me

いつも always/ forever

度でも endless times/ forever

何でも how many times/ many times, you can not only use in question, but 
also non question sentence to express many times

Comment: I'm positive this is a duplicate question, but I don't have time to look it up right now.  Search the site and you'll find several other similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct on the first one. いつも means "always".

I think you meant to say 何度｛なんど｝も. This means that something has or will happen "many times". It's as if the speaker can't count how many times it has or will occur.

何でも actually doesn't have to do with time at all but rather means "anything". It is similar to いつも, where there's a question word and も to mean "any---".